# Help transcribing a sentence

Tags: transcription

https://vocaroo.com/i/s0l7Cryl5rih

I'm trying to transcribe this sentence, what I have is the following but none of the characters seem to line up with words when looked up in a dictionary with the exception of `きょう`.

```
きょうのことしかできないかわいそなひとよね
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't hear the ひ at the beginning of the sentence or elongate the `そ` in `かわいそう`, which ended up throwing off the whole sentence when I was trying to look up words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is on-topic, but here is what she says:

> 「卑怯{ひきょう}なことしかできない、かわいそうな人{ひと}よね。」

meaning:

> "(Someone is)/(You are) a pitiful soul who cannot do anything except for unfair things."

Comment: Thanks, when I looked up the words in a dictionary I came to a similar conclusion of `Cowardice is the only thing this pathetic man is in a position to do.` Although your sentence is much easier to read in English.